# MassTrant - Consumer DI lifetime and registration options

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, event-bus

Im aware that it is recommended that instances which implement `IConsumer<T>` should be registered as Scoped instances.

```
public class OrderCompleteEventHandler : IConsumer<IOrderCompleteEvent>
{
    private readonly IOrderService _orderService;

    public OrderCompleteEventHandler(IOrderService orderService)
    { 
        _orderService = orderService;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IOrderCompleteEvent> context) => _orderService.DoSomething();
}
```

In the above example, does that mean `OrderCompleteEventHandler` is disposed after every message it consumes, which introduces a [captive dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) to all injected services?

What other options do we have when registering lifetimes of Consumers and their injected services?

Comment: Alexey explained it pretty well, and lifetime options depend upon which container you're using - but I would never use SingleInstance for a consumer, since they're created in a nested scope (depending upon the container).

Answer (score 1):

Consumers are encapsulated in a per-message lifecycle scope. That is done to ensure that messages can be consumed with great parallelism. If the load is great enough. MassTransit will use multiple consumer instances, so the overall throughput increases.

I am not sure what does it have to do with captive dependencies. Mark's article clearly describes that singletons that take dependencies that are registered with transient scope will effectively become singletons. Since consumers are not singletons by definition, they physically cannot create captive dependencies.

Consumers can have other dependencies that could be both transient, so will be instantiated per message, or scoped, or singletons.